# Blocks placed in content region appear in wrong positions

Tags: blocks, theming

Is there something I need to know about the way drupal handles blocks in the content region? I have a very bare bones omega subtheme with a single page promoted to front and two blocks in the content region positioned after the main content 'block' - but they show up before the main content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved the blocks around to different orders and back and they suddenly appeared in the correct positions. Seems that they just needed some fiddling. Please comment if you have a similar experience, I'm interested.

Comment: just had exactly the same problem with various blocks in the footer of my Omega theme, it occured when I added another block adjacent to it in the footer (in the post script region). I did as you say above, just reshuffled them (click Structure/Blocks) then moved the order of them around using the '+' and they eventually sorted themselves out. thanks, I thought i had some horrible memory coruption.

Comment: Weird problem. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Goto `/admin/appearance/settings/{your_subtheme}`, click on the Debugging tab on the left and then check the *Enable the debugging (placeholder) blocks for the selected roles.* option. This will display the regions and zones for you which will help you figure out the exact positions.

If everything seems to be fine after enabling the debugging settings, then you will need to check out the template files of your sub-theme. Sometimes messing up the page template files can lead to confusions like the one you are having now.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Everything showed up under the 'content' region as expected.

Comment: Glad that it helped. If your problem is solved, accept it as the answer. Else write in comments about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Sorry, to be clearer: the blocks and content were all within the 'content region', but still in the same order. I submitted my own answer to specifically detail what solved it.